# omnetpp always end with exit code as 1

Tags: omnet++

I'm trying to use Omnetpp++ 5.4.1 to do some simulations. However, each time I run a sample after installation. It  has the same problem: "Error: Network '' not found, check .ini and .ned files"

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The network you're trying to load does not exist. Your omnetpp.ini contains a line like

```
network = RSUExampleScenario
```

There should be a network (.ned file) with the same name in your project. It could start like this:

```
network RSUExampleScenario 
{
...
}
```

Make sure that the names in your omnetpp.ini and in the .ned file are the same. 
However, a good starting point (before doing such things in OMNeT++) is the [TicToc tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/).